# Real Time application of interface in java

Tags: java, interface

What is real time application of interface???

we can make implemented class without defining interface also.

for eg.

we have one interface animal and and have some method like eating etc.

and we can implement different class like dog ,cat etc from it.

but we can also make same dog,cat etc class with same methods eating without using interface.

then why to use interface???

Comment: All you need to do is hit this --> https://www.google.com/search?q=why+we+need+interface+in+java

Comment: real time interface is looking how the question votes go negative

Comment: Read Object Oriented Programing lessons before asking, try to understand then if you have specific issue ask here. There is a ton of things to say about interfaces and tons of different ways to architecture a full Animal classes implementation.

Comment: thanks for fast help i get it now.

Comment: i have read it from book but i didnt found my answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it allows you to decouple the implementation from the majority of your code.

The classic example is with collections, say `List` and its subclasses. I could define a list like this:

```
private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

...and mention only the concrete class, ArrayList, once in that code. For the rest of the time I'm working with the type of `list`, which is the `List` interface. If I wished to choose a different implementation of list for some reason, say `LinkedList`, or even some third party implementation I happened to find that worked better for my use case, then it'd be a trivial case of just swapping out one for the other. If on the other hand I'd used `ArrayList` everywhere in my code, as well as having to change all those types around I'd also have (potentially) used `ArrayList` specific methods not in the List interface, meaning I'd have to refactor my way around those also.

Comment: as long as a class implements the List aspect then you can use it as an List, you don't care about implementation stuff.If you want to write a method that use a Serializable object for example you use the interface and not its implementation. You should always write your code using the broadest type. If you don't need the List.get method then use something more generic like Collection but if you need it to be at least a List then use List. Interfaces are based on hypothesis and stipulations, remember that when implemented and selecting your interface you use